# CakePHP Stateless (Basic) Auth, where to call $this->Auth->login()?

Tags: php, cakephp, basic-authentication, cakephp-2.4

My CakePHP v2.4.X app supports both Basic and Form authentication (Form is for web users, and Basic is for Stateless access from Android App).

AppController.php contains the following $components declaration:

```
public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
                'authenticate' => array(
                        'Basic',
                        'Form',
                ),
        ),
);
```

From the doc on performing stateless Basic Auth:
    "In your login function just call $this->Auth->login() without any checks for POST data."

My issue is that if the user logs in using Basic Auth, they never trigger Users/login - so I am unsure where to place the $this->Auth->login() function.

Do I simply place this code in AppController/beforeFilter() and if the current user is not logged in I attempt login every time? ie:

```
if($this->Auth->loggedIn() == false)
{
    $this->Auth->login();
}
```

This doesn't seem right to me because if the user is using Form login they'll end up calling $this->Auth->login(); twice [once from AppController/beforeFilter(), and again from  UsersController/login()].

Also, when simply loading the login (via GET), the system will attempt to log them in and therefore return an error message.

I am also unsure how to determine if the user did login via Basic (as opposed to Form), and therefore set: "AuthComponent::$sessionKey" to false only when Basic was used.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-digest-and-basic-authentication-for-logging-in) related to basic auth doesn't correspond to what you are saying. Since 2.4 basic/digest auth doesn't need a login action at all. Just including `Basic` in the array for "authenticate" key for auth config is enough. It will automatically cause cake to check for required credentials when trying to access a protected action and if no credential or invalid credentials are provided appropriate headers are returned to the client.

Using both `Basic` and `Form` authenticators together can be problematic. I suggest modifying auth config in beforeFilter to use only either one of them conditionally by using appropriate conditions to check if request is from mobile app or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I still need to test whether it works as you said above, but yes you are correct that the 2.4 documentation states it performs auto-login.
What kind of checks would you recommend implementing to detect if request is from mobile app? The only real difference should be that the request contains Basic auth headers?

Comment: Normally mobile apps use a RESTful API which returns json/xml to get info the server. You can use `api` prefix for your api with urls like /api/foo/bar.json. Configure the `api` prefix in CakePHP's router and then to check if it's a request from mobile app just check for the url prefix.

Comment: Hi ADmad, is it possible to use the router prefix, but have it map to non-prefixed functions? ie: api/foo/bar.json would map to api_bar() in the foo controller, but is it possible to have it map directly to bar() in the foo controller instead?